# Align centered math-blocks

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

How can I align multiple math blocks, such that each block is centered.

In my example the `1` should be printed centered above the `11` and so on.

I guess this can be done with `minipage`s, but I believe there is an easier and nicer solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&1  & &2  & &3  & &4  & &5  & &6  & &7  & &8\\
&11 & &22 & &33 & &44 & &55 & &66 & &77 & &88
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a `matrix` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' env.
\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{matrix}
 1  &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8 \\
11 &22 &33 &44 &55 &66 &77 &88
\end{matrix} 
\]

\end{document}
```

To change the column spacing, modify the parameter `\arraycolsep`, as in

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{15pt} % default value: 5pt
```

---

Here are two more possibilities: (a) an `array` environment and (b) a `tabular` environment that uses a centered version of the `p` column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\arraycolsep{15pt} % default value: 5pt
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*{8}{c}}
 1  &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8 \\
11 &22 &33 &44 &55 &66 &77 &88
\end{array} 
\]

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{C{1cm}}}
 1  &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8 \\
11 &22 &33 &44 &55 &66 &77 &88
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a parameter like `width=\textwidth` (which would simulate aligned equations, wouldn't it?)

Comment: @Ben - Are you thinking of `tabular` environments and the `p` column type? I've posted an addendum to show making use of this idea.

Comment: I thought of an other situation, where I only want to align 1 with 11, 2 with 22 and 3 with 33. `align` automatically sets the gap between the blocks to fit the hole `\textwidth`

Comment: @Ben - I’m afraid I didn’t understand that comment. Could you rephrase?

Answer (score 3):

Here, with a TABstack.  The inter-column gap and inter-row baselinekip are readily settable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{8pt}% BETWEEN-COLUMN GAP
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}% BETWEEN ROW SKIP
\begin{document}
\tabbedCenterstack{
1  &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8\\
11 &22 &33 &44 &55 &66 &77 &88
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The cells are here set in text mode, but that default can be changed with `\stackMath`  (or `\TABstackMath`).

Based on the OP's follow up comment, I was *astounded* to find (in my own package no less) that I can set the inter-column stack gap to `\fill` to achieve a full-width solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,lipsum}
\setstacktabbedgap{\fill}% BETWEEN-COLUMN GAP
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}% BETWEEN ROW SKIP
\begin{document}
\noindent\tabbedCenterstack{
1  &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8\\
11 &22 &33 &44 &55 &66 &77 &88
}\medskip

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my comments to @Mico's solution.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for making me think harder on that question.  I found that I can simply achieve a full-width solution wtih `\setstacktabbedgap{\fill}`.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to set a `\textwidth`-wide table, with each column having the same width with a centred alignment, containing math content in `\displaystyle`. This matches to some extent what is provided by `align*` with the requirement of spreading out the content across the text block (or whatever width you supply):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}X<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &1  & &2  & &3  & &4  & &5  & &6  & &7  & &8  \\
  &11 & &22 & &33 & &44 & &55 & &66 & &77 & &88
\end{align*}

\[
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{8}{M} }
    1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  \\[\jot]
    11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 55 & 66 & 77 & 88
  \end{tabularx}
\]

\[
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{4}{M} }
    1  & 2  & 3  & 4  \\[\jot]
    11 & 22 & 33 & 44
  \end{tabularx}
\]

\[
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{4}{M} }
    abcdef  &    4567    & qrstuvwxy  & 90  \\[\jot]
     123    & ghijklmnop &     8      & z
  \end{tabularx}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Placing full-width `tabularx` environments inside unnumbered display-math environments seems like overkill. Prefacing then with `\noindent` instructions should suffice, right?

Comment: @Mico: Indeed. The motivation for keeping them inside a display math environment is to ensure similar spacing around a mathematically-filled structure.